# Looking for specific polygon boundaries of DMA regions

Tags: polygon, carto, administrative-boundaries

I am trying to create a map in CartoDB and I need 2 specific polygons for it. The regions are:

```
DMA_id, DMA_Name
743 Anchorage, AK
744 Honolulu, HI
```

I searched every source I have and those two are missing in every file. Anyone may help here?

**Edit:** I managed to find a shapefile of all the areas in Honolulu. I join them and create a new, one polygon that contains all the Honolulu. So, only Anchorage remains.

Comment: [Is this any good?](https://transition.fcc.gov/dtv/markets/maps_current/Anchorage_AK.pdf) - it's in PDF format and is old (2009), but if you have a map of the counties to hand you might be able to reverse-engineer from that (the shapefile on the same page is 404ing, sadly). Neilsen own the copyright to DMA regions so don't rely on free shapefiles being up forever...

Answer (score 1):

Would this dataset be helpful for you? http://geocommons.com/overlays/106797 It contains Digital Marketing Areas (DMA)for the United States of America and it's exportable as a geospatial vector file uploadable to CartoDB.

Unfortunately, I'm not sharing it in the Data Library section because of:

`The DMA boundaries and DMA data are owned solely and exclusively by The Nielsen Company. Any use and or reproduction of these materials without the express written consent of The Nielsen Company is strictly prohibited.`

Comment: useful resource, but it only has the contiguous USA, as well as the copyright issue. Seems to be the case in all in-the-wild shapefiles I could find.

Comment: I found it but it doesn't contain the two regions I need.